# python - make new column summing values from columnA with conditions in columnB

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    team  W   L  GF  GA       date  home_ind  last10
67   ARI  1   0   3   2 2016-11-01         1       1
99   ARI  1   0   2   2 2016-11-03         1       1
129  ARI  1   0   4   3 2016-10-15         1       1
171  ARI  1   0   5   4 2016-10-27         0       1
241  ARI  0  10   1   5 2016-11-04         0       0
316  ARI  0  10   3   5 2016-10-25         0       1
331  ARI  0  10   2   3 2016-10-21         0       1
334  ARI  0  10   2   3 2016-10-29         1       1
335  ARI  0  10   2   5 2016-10-20         0       1
340  ARI  0  10   4   7 2016-10-18         0       1
341  ARI  0  10   2   3 2016-10-23         0       1
```

I have this information for 30 different teams.

What I would like to do is make additional columns summing the values from one column, based on conditions from other columns.

For example, I would like a new column that adds the values from GF, but ONLY when home_ind = 1 AND last10 = 1 AND team = ARI. The value that results would be the same value for the column for each team. So for the example that I laid out, the results would look like this:

```
    team  W   L  GF  GA       date  home_ind  last10   GF_H_10
67   ARI  1   0   3   2 2016-11-01         1       1        11
99   ARI  1   0   2   2 2016-11-03         1       1        11
129  ARI  1   0   4   3 2016-10-15         1       1        11
171  ARI  1   0   5   4 2016-10-27         0       1         0
241  ARI  0  10   1   5 2016-11-04         0       0         0
316  ARI  0  10   3   5 2016-10-25         0       1         0
331  ARI  0  10   2   3 2016-10-21         0       1         0
334  ARI  0  10   2   3 2016-10-29         1       1        11
335  ARI  0  10   2   5 2016-10-20         0       1         0
340  ARI  0  10   4   7 2016-10-18         0       1         0
341  ARI  0  10   2   3 2016-10-23         0       1         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other solutions here are specific to the ARI team. This performs a groupby on the team, allowing the operation to be completed for the other 30 teams. I'm not sure which you're after.

Performing the groupby on team and then joining the results to the original dataframe is the main idea behind this solution. There is cleanup afterward on the eligibility criteria you define.

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'team':['ARI']*11+['BWI']*4,
                   'W':[1]*4+[0]*7+[1,1,0,0],
                   'GF':[3,2,4,5,1,3,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'GA':[2,2,3,4,5,5,3,3,5,7,3,1,1,1,1],
                   'home_ind':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
                   'last10':[1]*4+[0]+[1]*6+[1,0,1,1]})

# define a mask
df2 = df.assign(elig=(df['home_ind'] == 1) & (df['last10'] == 1))


# group on team and join the results to the original dataframe
df2 = df2.join(df2[df2['elig']].groupby('team')['GF'].sum(), on='team', rsuffix='_H_10')

# clean up the result column
df2.loc[~df2['elig'], 'GF_H_10'] = 0
```

Given the dataframe

```
    GA  GF  W  home_ind  last10 team
0    2   3  1         1       1  ARI
1    2   2  1         1       1  ARI
2    3   4  1         1       1  ARI
3    4   5  1         0       1  ARI
4    5   1  0         0       0  ARI
5    5   3  0         0       1  ARI
6    3   2  0         0       1  ARI
7    3   2  0         1       1  ARI
8    5   2  0         0       1  ARI
9    7   4  0         0       1  ARI
10   3   2  0         0       1  ARI
11   1   2  1         1       1  BWI
12   1   2  1         1       0  BWI
13   1   2  0         0       1  BWI
14   1   2  0         0       1  BWI
```

The output is

```
    GA  GF  W  home_ind  last10 team   elig  GF_H_10
0    2   3  1         1       1  ARI   True       11
1    2   2  1         1       1  ARI   True       11
2    3   4  1         1       1  ARI   True       11
3    4   5  1         0       1  ARI  False        0
4    5   1  0         0       0  ARI  False        0
5    5   3  0         0       1  ARI  False        0
6    3   2  0         0       1  ARI  False        0
7    3   2  0         1       1  ARI   True       11
8    5   2  0         0       1  ARI  False        0
9    7   4  0         0       1  ARI  False        0
10   3   2  0         0       1  ARI  False        0
11   1   2  1         1       1  BWI   True        2
12   1   2  1         1       0  BWI  False        0
13   1   2  0         0       1  BWI  False        0
14   1   2  0         0       1  BWI  False        0
```

Comment: you're correct. i need to do a group by on the team so that this can be done for all 30 teams. i really like your approach, but for some reason, the only number that is showing up is 10....

Comment: Hmmmmm, even now? I messed up my original post and had to edit. Can you reproduce the tables I added? In my original post I was incorrectly assigning the first value of the series produced by the sum function, so all of the teams would have the same value. Should be fixed now.

Comment: You're very welcome. rsuffix is an argument of the pandas [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) function. When there are collisions between columns in a merge or join, you can specify the suffix used to differentiate between the two. In our case, we would have two columns named 'GF': the original in the left dataframe and the sum produced in the right groupby dataframe. Passing in the rsuffix parameter, modifies the colliding columns in the right dataframe, and passing in an lsuffix parameter would modify the colliding columns in the original.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

first make a boolean slicer called criteria and then use assignment:

```
criteria = (df['home_ind'] == 1) & (df['last10'] == 1) &  (df['team'] == 'ARI')
df.loc[criteria,'GF_H_10'] = df[criteria]['GF'].sum()
```

which gives:

```
     GA  GF   L  W        date  home_ind  last10 team  GF_H_10
67    2   3   0  1  2016-11-01         1       1  ARI  11.0000
99    2   2   0  1  2016-11-03         1       1  ARI  11.0000
129   3   4   0  1  2016-10-15         1       1  ARI  11.0000
171   4   5   0  1  2016-10-27         0       1  ARI      nan
241   5   1  10  0  2016-11-04         0       0  ARI      nan
316   5   3  10  0  2016-10-25         0       1  ARI      nan
331   3   2  10  0  2016-10-21         0       1  ARI      nan
334   3   2  10  0  2016-10-29         1       1  ARI  11.0000
335   5   2  10  0  2016-10-20         0       1  ARI      nan
340   7   4  10  0  2016-10-18         0       1  ARI      nan
341   3   2  10  0  2016-10-23         0       1  ARI      nan
```

then to make the nan become 0.0:

```
df['GF_H_10'].fillna(0.0,inplace=True)
```